# What's the most preferred navigation type?

Tags: navigation, accordion, mega-menu

I'm creating a website for streaming music, viewing lyrics, music videos, photos, artists, reviews, news, etc.

I've been wondering, what do users like best?

I've been caught between

- a **basic drop down sub menu**,
- a **mega menu**,

  > [image]
- or a **slide out accordion styled menu**

  > [image]

**Any suggestions?**

The site has a dark navigation, light background, main fonts are Gibson, Helvetia, and Lato.

And pages include:

- Artists > Genres > Subgenres (about 5)
- Artists > Lyrics
- Artists > collections
- Photo Galleries
- Read > Features
- Read > Articles
- Read > Franchise (about 3)
- News
- Watch > Music Videos
- Watch > Interviews
- Watch > playlists
- Watch > extras
- Reviews
- Listen

Then I'd like to fit in some links to some social networks and a user login / sign up area or links.

This is more based on personal opinion and every opinion matters!

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be based on personal opinion, but on research for the best information architecture.

The IA should be derived from the content (its volume and natural sectioning), and oriented by the target audience.
Ask yourself a couple of guiding questions, and narrow it down a little.

Who should use the website? What are they used to? What are the first things they will be looking for?

Than just test it. You can prepare a [pretotype](http://www.pretotyping.org/), but that is not really necessary at such stage. You don't even have to develop anything. Have some real people fitting your target audience and spy on them (not like, creepy spy - just watch their habits) while they use similar products.

Generally speaking (from the top of my head, again, this should be researched with your case), if I had to choose, I think I would go for the accordion. Mega-menu is disqualified right away as there's not nearly enough sectioning in the content (you only have a first/second level menus), and the basic dropdown top menu seems a misfit for such a website (it feels more formal to me).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I ended up using a slide menu with an accordion, it's amazing!

Comment: you're welcome, @user3250715. please tick the answer accepted if it solved your issue.